# save recyclerview after change item position by drag

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop, sharedpreferences

I have a `recyclerview` that I can change its items position by drag everything. It's working fine.

But after I turn off the app the items gets back to the way it was before how can I save the new position. I think `SharedPreferences` will be a good solution but i don't know how to use it.

How can I do that.

My Code is here..

```
public class MyItemTouchHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {

    private final ItemTouchHelpAdapter mAdapter;

    public MyItemTouchHelper(ItemTouchHelpAdapter mAdapter) {
        this.mAdapter = mAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isItemViewSwipeEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void clearView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);
        viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(viewHolder.itemView.getContext(),R.color.cardview_shadow_end_color)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onSelectedChanged(@Nullable RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
        super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState);
        if (actionState==ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_DRAG){

            viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(
                    Color.LTGRAY
            );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        final int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
        final int swipeFlags = 0;
        return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags,swipeFlags);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        mAdapter.onItemMove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(),target.getAdapterPosition());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        mAdapter.onItemSwipe(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

    }
}
```

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> implements
         ItemTouchHelpAdapter{
    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";
    private ArrayList<String> mgamename = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ItemTouchHelper mTouchHelper;
    private Context mcontext;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> mgamename, Context mcontext) {
        this.mgamename = mgamename;
        this.mcontext = mcontext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_listitem,parent,false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onBindViewHolder: called.");
        holder.gamename.setText(mgamename.get(position));

        holder.gamename.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (position==0){
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(),cc.class);
                    mcontext.startActivity(intent1);}
                if (position==1){
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(),tc.class);
                    mcontext.startActivity(intent1);
                }
                if (position==2){
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(),k.class);
                    mcontext.startActivity(intent1);
                }
                if (position==3){
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(),ccp.class);
                    mcontext.startActivity(intent1);
                }
                if (position==4){
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(),tcp.class);
                    mcontext.startActivity(intent1);
                }
                if (position==5){
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(),kp.class);
                    mcontext.startActivity(intent1);
                }
                if (position==6){
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(),balot.class);
                    mcontext.startActivity(intent1);
                }
                if (position==7){
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(),tarneeb31.class);
                    mcontext.startActivity(intent1);
                }
                if (position==8){
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(),tarneeb61.class);
                    mcontext.startActivity(intent1);
                }
                if (position==9){
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(),tarneeb41.class);
                    mcontext.startActivity(intent1);
                }
                if (position==10){
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(),tarneeb41e.class);
                    mcontext.startActivity(intent1);
                }
                if (position==11){
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(),tarneeb400.class);
                    mcontext.startActivity(intent1);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mgamename.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPostion) {
        String fromNote = mgamename.get(fromPosition);
        mgamename.remove(fromNote);
        mgamename.add(toPostion,fromNote);
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition,toPostion);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSwipe(int postion) {
        mgamename.remove(postion);
        notifyItemRemoved(postion);

    }
    public void setmTouchHelper(ItemTouchHelper touchHelper){
        this.mTouchHelper = touchHelper;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements
            View.OnTouchListener, GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {

        TextView gamename;
        RelativeLayout parentLayout;
        TextView number;
        CardView cardView;
        GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            gamename = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.gamename);
            number = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.number);
            parentLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
            cardView = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardv);
            mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(itemView.getContext(),this);
            itemView.setOnTouchListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            cardView.callOnClick();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            mTouchHelper.startDrag(this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private ArrayList<String> mgamename = new ArrayList<>();
    private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;
    public static final String LIST_OF_SORTED_DATA_ID = "json_list_sorted_data_id";
    public final static String PREFERENCE_FILE = "preference_file";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mSharedPreferences = this.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_FILE,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();


        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Log.d(TAG,"onCreate: started.");

        mgamename.add("Complex Complex");

        mgamename.add("Trix Complex");

        mgamename.add("Kingdoms");

        mgamename.add("Complex Complex Partner");

        mgamename.add("Trix Complex Partner");

        mgamename.add("Kingdoms Partner");

        mgamename.add("Balot");

        mgamename.add("Tarneeb 31");

        mgamename.add("Tarneeb 61");

        mgamename.add("Tarneeb 41(Syrian)");

        mgamename.add("Tarneeb 41 (Egyptian)");

        mgamename.add("Tarneeb 400");

        initRecyclerView();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case  R.id.item1:
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                myIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String shareBody = "An App to Calculate All Your Beloved Games Such As Balot Tarneeb Trix etc";
                String shareSub = "Cards Game Calculator";
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,shareSub);
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,shareBody);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent,"Share Using"));}
                switch (item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.item2:
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("About")
                        .setMessage("Calculation Note For Your Beloved Games Such As Balot Taneeb Trix.  Enjoy!")

                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }

                        })

                        .show();
                alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private void initRecyclerView(){

        Log.d(TAG,"initRecyclerView: init recyclerview");
        RecyclerView recyclerview = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        final RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mgamename,this);

        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback = new MyItemTouchHelper(adapter);
        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
        adapter.setmTouchHelper(itemTouchHelper);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerview);
        recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

please help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Use Room database for this.Store your list in your local database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreference like this

1. Save data as string with comma separation on Exit time from app
2. Split in array when you return again and assign them to ArrayList

First Initialization when your open app

```
/**
 * Call it in onCreate where your first set data
 */
private void initArrayList(){

    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("array_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String data = sp.getString("myarray", "");

    if(data.equals("")) {
        mgamename.add("Complex Complex");
        mgamename.add("Trix Complex");
        mgamename.add("Kingdoms");
        mgamename.add("Complex Complex Partner");
        mgamename.add("Trix Complex Partner");
        mgamename.add("Kingdoms Partner");
        mgamename.add("Balot");
        mgamename.add("Tarneeb 31");
        mgamename.add("Tarneeb 61");
        mgamename.add("Tarneeb 41(Syrian)");
        mgamename.add("Tarneeb 41 (Egyptian)");
        mgamename.add("Tarneeb 400");
    }else{
        String [] array = data.split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            mgamename.add(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Save data in sharedPreference when you exit or on data position change by drag

```
 /**
 * Save your array list in SharedPreference when you exit
 * you can implement it onBackPressed or onDestroy in your Activity lifecycle
 * OR you can call it when you drag item and ArrayList data position changed 
 * @param arr
 */
public void saveDatOnExit(ArrayList<String> arr) {
    if (arr == null) return;

    String array = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        if(i<(arr.size()-1)){
            array+=arr.get(i)+",";
        }else{
            array+=arr.get(i);
        }
    }
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("array_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sp.edit().putString("myarray", array).commit();
}
```

But best way, use Sqlite Database